# How to map two different routes to the same Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I have two routes in `server.js` :

```
  app.use("/credit/success", require("./credit/credit-handler"));
  app.use("/credit/fail", require("./credit/credit-handler"));
```

And `credit-handler` :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// @route  GET credit success
// @desc   Get credit success screen
// @access Public

router.get("/success", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.sendFile("./credit/SuccessTransaction.html");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error :" + err.message);
  }
});

// @route  GET credit failure
// @desc   Get credit fail screen
// @access Public

router.get("/fail", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.sendFile("./credit/FailTransaction.html");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error :" + err.message);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I refer the request `/credit/success` to the `success` function , and 
the request `/credit/fail` to the `fail` function in the router ?

Comment: I think you can just update the middleware to endpoint /credit. Remove /success and /fail from server.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the server.js middleware usage mentioned below:

```
app.use("/credit", require("./credit/credit-handler"));
```

Then you can access the end point by accessing i.e

```
/credit/success
/credit/fail
```

Answer (score 1):

In server.js you will need a single line:

```
app.use("/credit", require("./credit/credit-handler"));
```

That will add to the '/credit' path whatever you have in the credit-handler